# Get SQL Server plan cache statements without system statements

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, caching

I want get all statements from SQL Server plan cache but without statement made by SQL Server.

This is query.

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    ss.query_plan_hash
FROM 
    (SELECT DISTINCT 
         plan_handle
     FROM 
         sys.dm_exec_cached_plans WITH(NOLOCK)) AS qs
OUTER APPLY 
    sys.dm_exec_query_plan(qs.plan_handle) tp
INNER JOIN 
    sys.databases d ON tp.dbid = d.database_id
INNER JOIN
    sys.dm_exec_query_stats ss ON ss.plan_handle = qs.plan_handle
WHERE
    d.name = 'pokus'
```

I know that in `sys.dm_exec_requests`, if the column `session_id` > 50 then system statements are filtered out. But for plan cache I don´t know how to do it. Please help.